# Using Order property in React-Responsive UI

Tags: reactjs, responsive-design

I'm learning responsive UI.What I want to o here is when screen size comes to `sm={6}` the order of the `<div>` should be changed.I tried it using order ,but It didn't work.Below is my code

```js
import React from 'react';
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';

export const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  item1: {
    order: 1,
    [theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: {
      order: 2,
    },
  },
  item2: {
    order: 2,
    [theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: {
      order: 1,
    },
  },
}));

export default function App() {
  const dataSource = [
    {
      name: 'HSA Bank',
      cardTitle: 'Medical FSA Plan',
      title: 'General Purpose Flexible Spending Accounts(FSA)',
      cdes1: 'Annual Max Contribution',
      cdes2: 'Use it or Lose it policy (Grace period)',
      des1:
        "A Flexible Spending Account can be used to pay for qualified out-of-pocket health care costs. Because money you contribute to your FSA isn't taxed, you can reduce your overall healthcare expenses. Typically, you must use all money in an FSA within your employer's plan year (known ass 'use it or lose it'). Some employers offer a 2.5 month grace period or allow you to rollover up to $500.",
      des2: 'The 2020 IRS contribution limit is $2,750.',
    },
    {
      name: 'Health Net',
      cardTitle: 'Dependent Care FSA Plan',
      title: 'Dependent care FSA(DCFSA)',
      cdes1: 'Max individual Contributor for Married but filling as seperately',
      cdes2: 'Max Married Contribution for Filling Joinly or Single Parent As Head',
      cdes3: 'Use it or Lose it policy (Grace period)',
      des1:
        'A Dependent Care Flexible Spending Account is a pre-tax benefit account used to pay for eligible dependent care services such as preschool, summer day camp, before/after school programs, and child or elder care.2020 IRS contribution limit: $2,500 if married and filing seperately; $5,000 if married and filing jointly or filing as a single/head of household.',
      des2:
        'DCFSA annual contribution limits always align with the calender year (which may or may not align with your plan year). NOTE: when filing jointly, the IRS requires both spouses have W-2 earned income during the year',
    },
  ];

  const classes = useStyles();

  const description = dataSource.map((item) => {
    return (
      <Grid container spacing={3} style={{ backgroundColor: 'ash', paddingBottom: 100 }}>
        <Grid container direction="column" xs={12} sm={6} md={4} className={classes.item1}>
          <div>
            <Card>
              <CardContent>
                <h1>{item.name}</h1>
                <h3>{item.cardTitle}</h3>
              </CardContent>
            </Card>
          </div>
        </Grid>
        <Grid container direction="column" xs={12} sm={6} md={8}>
          <div style={{ backgroundColor: 'blue', paddingLeft: 50 }}>Test</div>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    );
  });

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Container maxWidth="lg" style={{ paddingTop: 50 }}>
        {description}
      </Container>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Comment: Please refer to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54726871/changing-the-order-of-grid-item-stacking-in-material-ui

Comment: I tried the same way.But I don't get the  correct output.

Comment: Please check <Grid> only classes.item1 is there static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgget to add item2 class in second grid tag

```
<Grid container direction="column" xs={12} sm={6} md={8} className={classes.item2}>
```